# Mockito doAnswer throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException for unknown reason

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito

I want to mock action `requestPermission(@NonNull String permission, int requestCode)` of my PermissionHostCompat class.

```
public class PermissionHostCompat {

    (...)

    public void requestPermission(@NonNull String permission, int requestCode) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
    }

    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        if (activity != null) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
        } else if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(fragment, permissions, requestCode);
        } else {
            fragmentv4.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
        }
    }

    (...)
}
```

There is how I do it:

```
@Mock
PermissionHostCompat permissionHostCompat;

//...

Answer<Void> requestPermissionAction = new Answer<Void>() {
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            // some code
            return null;
        }
    };
doAnswer(requestPermissionAction).when(permissionHostCompat)
    .requestPermission(anyString(), anyInt());
```

And it throws me error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
> Invalid use of argument matchers! 
>   
> 0 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
>
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>   
> //incorrect:
>   
> someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>   
> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>   
> For example:
>   
> //correct:
>   
> someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

I have no idea why. I tried also `any(String.class)`, `any(int.class)` and combination between all of options.

My imports:

> import static org.mockito.Matchers.any; 
>   
> import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt; 
>   
> import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString; 
>   
> import staticorg.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer; 
>   
> import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

Mockito version: 1.10.19

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce this exception with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Works on MCVE. Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post it? So others can reproduce the error.

Comment: your code works for me - you didn't share the problematic code, which is .... well unknown at the moment

Comment: Yeah... but I have no idea now what might be cause of the problem anymore so I don't know what to post. Thanks for trying. I will close I guess or response back if I will find something that bothers me. It worked on example project with 2 classes only.

Comment: I would start by commenting out the overloaded method taking the String array to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You aren't running this in an APK with Proguard enabled, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Try if it will work with Mockito 2. But imports should be changed:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
```